# Jmeter clear resultFile for each run

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan, where i have two thread groups, first thread group will run and will log the result into a file, the logged  file will be the input to the second thread group.
Now, for doing this in thread group one i added BeanShell PostProcessor script as follows, but it works as follows

1. open jmeter and run the test plan (log file "testing.csv" will be created as fresh)
2. For first time "isHeaderWritten" property is false.
3. No without closing and reopening the jmeter, run the script again. i expect the log file "testing.csv" must be truncated and add the values freshly. But what acually happening is "testing.csv" file is appended with the new values.
4. Now, close the jmeter and open again, this time log file "testing.csv" will be truncated and fresh new values are added.

How to clear the file and re-write the records for each run (without closing the jemeter)

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;

threadName=ctx.getThread().getThreadName();
log.info("threadName: "+threadName);

isHeaderWritten = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("isHeaderWritten","false");
 fileName="C:\\response\\testing.csv";
log.info("isHeaderWritten: "+isHeaderWritten);
if(isHeaderWritten == "true"){  
    f = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);   
    fileHeader = "requestStatus,cNumber,pId,id,token";
}else{
    log.error("isHeaderWritten:"+isHeaderWritten);
    f = new FileOutputStream(fileName, false);
    fileHeader = "requestStatus,cNumber,pId,id,token";
}
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
if(isHeaderWritten == "false"){ 
    print(fileHeader);  
    JMeterUtils.setProperty("isHeaderWritten", "true");
}
log.info("Test results will be written to file "+fileName);

cNumber=vars.get("cNumber");
log.info("cNumber"+cNumber);
pId = vars.get("pId");
log.info("pId"+pId);
pmId = vars.get("pmId");
log.info("pmId"+pmId);
tTxt = vars.get("tTxt");
log.info("tTxt"+tTxt);

responseCode=prev.getResponseCode();
log.info("responseCode  of "+requestString+ " is "+responseCode);
requestStatus = "Success";
if(!"201".equals(responseCode)){
    requestStatus = "Failure"+","+cNumber+","+pId+","+pmId+","+tTxt;
}
result = requestStatus;
if("Success".equals(requestStatus)){

    responseData=new String(data);
    log.info("responseData  of "+requestString+ " is "+responseData);
    requestString=requestStatus+","+cNumber+","+pId+","+pmId+","+tTxt;
    result = requestString;
    log.info("result"+result);
}
log.debug(result);
print(result);
f.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are global to JMeter, so can be used to communicate between threads and thread groups
>
> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

So once you execute this line:

```
JMeterUtils.setProperty("isHeaderWritten", "true");
```

the property `isHeaderWritten` will become `true` and will remain `true` until you restart JMeter.

The easiest solution would be adding a [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your test plan (this Thread Group is being executed **after** any other thread group(s)) and add a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the following code:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore();
org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.setProperty("isHeaderWritten", "false");
```

---

[Since JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting mainly because [Groovy performance is much better than Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so consider migrating to [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language on next available opportunity

Comment: It is working after doing a adjustment. created Beanshell sampler with script as
"try{
 //SampleResult.setIgnore();
 org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.setProperty("isHeaderWritten", "false");
}catch(Exception e){
 log.error("exception is : "+e);
 throw e;
}
"